# How to avoid running multiple useEffect when I pass `react.element` as a props?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a `List` component to control same logic for list.
And I'm passing rendered react element as a props to the `List` component.

But, useEffect in child component runs every time when the state changed.

Simplified code is like below:

`saga`

```js
export function* fetchPosts(action) {
  try {
    const res = yield call_api(action.url);
    yield put(actions.appendPosts(res.data.posts);  // state.posts = state.posts.concat(action.payload.posts)
  } finally {
    yield put(actions.setLoading(false));  // state.meta.loading = false;
    yield put(actions.setFetched(true));   // state.meta.fetched = true;
  }
}
```

`Posts.jsx`

```js
export const Posts = (props) => {
  const { meta, posts } = useSelector((state) => state.postState);

  const ListItems = () => {
    return (
      posts.map(d => (
      <Post
        ...
        />
      ))
    )
  }

  return (
    <List 
      itemsElement={ <ListItems />}  // $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
      ...
    />
  )
}
```

`List.jsx`

```js
export const List = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <>
      ...
      { props.itemsElement }
      ...
    </>
  );
}


export default List
```

`Post.jsx`

```js
export const Post = (props) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // This code runs every time when the state changed
  }, [])

  return (
    ...
  );
}

export default Post
```

And if I change Posts code like below, useEffect runs only once.

`Posts.jsx`

```js
export const Posts = (props) => {


  return (
    posts.map(d => (
      <Post
        ...
      />
    ))
  )
}
```

How can I avoid this?

I'm thinking of changing the state at once like below,

```js
setData: (state, action) => {
  state.posts = state.posts.concat(action.payload.posts)
  state.meta.loading = action.payload.loading
  state.meta.fetched = action.payload.fetched
},
```

But I think maybe there is a better way.
I'd appreciate it if you could point me to a better way.

Comment: Where does `posts` come from inside of `Posts`? Is a `key` prop passed into each `<Post>`?

Comment: @windowsill yes, key props passed in to Post. 
And posts is a array in the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue.

### Update

This seems better for me in this case because I don't have to use `useCallback`.
I didn't realize these two were different, but they are different.

`Posts.jsx`

```
export const Posts = (props) => {
  const { meta, posts } = useSelector((state) => state.postState);

  return (
    <List 
      itemsElement={  // $$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: Symbol(react.fragment)
        <>
        {
          posts.map(d => (
            <Post
             ...
            />
          ))
        }
        </>
      }  
      ...
    />
  )
}
```

### Original Answer

I need to wrap `ListItems` function in `useCallback`.

`Posts.jsx`

```
export const Posts = (props) => {
  const { meta, posts } = useSelector((state) => state.postState);

  const ListItems = useCallback(() => {
    return (
      posts.map(d => (
      <Post
        ...
        />
      ))
    )
  }, [posts]); 

  return (
    <List 
      itemsElement={ <ListItems />}  // $$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: () => {…}
      ...
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem you are running into:

- You are defining the `<ListItems />` React Component **each time** that `Posts` re-renders.
- Because of that, `ListItems`'s children `<Post />` then are unmounted and remounted, hence the effect always running.

Instead, you should be ["thinking in a react"](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and make a new component that accepts the `posts` as a *prop* rather than defining it within a closure (aka your `Posts` component).

Each `Post` will still re-render, but its not a full unmount / remount, so the effect won't run again. If you'd like to prevent the render altogether, you can memoize the component with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Here's a simplified example that doesn't use sagas but fakes a *fetch* call to generate some "posts" data:

```js
const { React, ReactDOM } = window;
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const mockedPosts = Array(3)
  .fill()
  .map((_, i) => ({ id: Math.random(), name: `Post number ${i + 1}` }));

const fetchMockPost = (length) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const mockPost = {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: `Post number ${length + 1}`,
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(mockPost);
    }, 100);
  });
};

const Post = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted:", props);
    return () => {
      console.log("unmounted:", props);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <li>
      Post Name: <b>{props.name}</b>
    </li>
  );
};

const Posts = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post key={post.id} name={post.name} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(mockedPosts);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        This react app passes <code>posts</code> as a <em>prop</em> so our
        component will just re-render, rather than completely unmount and mount.
        When a new post is fetched here, only the newly fetched post is{" "}
        <code>mounted</code>. The other posts <em>do</em> re-render, but their
        effect doesn't run again.
      </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fetchMockPost(state.length).then((newPost) => {
            setState((prevState) => [...prevState, newPost]);
          });
        }}
      >
        Fetch new post
      </button>
      <hr />
      <Posts posts={state} />
    </div>
  );
};

const AppThatRedefinesPosts = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(mockedPosts);

  const RedefinedPosts = () => {
    return (
      <ul>
        {state.map((post) => (
          <Post key={post.id} name={post.name} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        This react app always redefines <code>Posts</code> thus they always
        unmount/mount when a new post is fetched. You can see the logs show
        everything <code>unmount</code> and then everything <code>mount</code> afterward.
      </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fetchMockPost(state.length).then((newPost) => {
            setState((prevState) => [...prevState, newPost]);
          });
        }}
      >
        Fetch new post
      </button>
      <hr />
      <RedefinedPosts />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
ReactDOM.render(<AppThatRedefinesPosts />, document.getElementById("app-original"));
```

```css
#app,
#app-original {
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: beige;
}

/* misc, help with scrolling with virtual console */
body {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app-original"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @romellem. I really appreciate. 
Do you still see any issues with my second approach? - (without using `<Some />`) because I don't see re-mounting with that.

Comment: No, if you use `posts.map(p => <Post {...p} />)` directly instead of a component that accepts `posts` as a prop, that should be the same. I would recommend using that inline version instead of `const listItems = () => posts.map(...); <List itemsElement={listItems()}`. Using a custom `renderFunction()` instead of a React Element directly [is considered an anti-pattern](https://dev.to/jcutrell/react-anti-pattern-renderthing-50nd). Just make sure within your `map` loop that you are using a unique [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for every `<Post />`.

Comment: Oh, good to know that it's an anti-pattern. The posting you mentioned is helpful. Thanks for that.